# Window navigation wrap around in Vim

Tags: vim

I would like it so that typing <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> from the right most window would focus the left most window in VIM. Obviously it would be handy for this to work in all directions.

My main motivation is for use with NERDTree. I typically have the following setup:

```
|----------|----------|-----------|
|          |          |           |
| NERDTree |   File1  |   File2   |
|          |          |           |
|          |----------|-----------|
|          |          |           |
|          |   File3  |   File4   |
|          |          |           |
|----------|----------|-----------|
```

If I want to open a new file in the same window as `File4` I currently have to type <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> and it would be quite nice to achieve the same result with <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>.

Comment: You'll most certainly have to write some code to get that accomplished and map it to desired key-combo. Check `:h window-move-cursor`; movement commands are listed there.

Comment: That was my thought. Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with vim scripting just yet :)

Answer (score 7):

You'd have to override the default commands in your `$HOME/.vimrc` with your own mappings that include this extra logic. When the normal move doesn't change the window any more (i.e. we're at the border already), jump to the other side.

```
"
" Wrap window-move-cursor
"
function! s:GotoNextWindow( direction, count )
  let l:prevWinNr = winnr()
  execute a:count . 'wincmd' a:direction
  return winnr() != l:prevWinNr
endfunction

function! s:JumpWithWrap( direction, opposite )
  if ! s:GotoNextWindow(a:direction, v:count1)
    call s:GotoNextWindow(a:opposite, 999)
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <C-w>h :<C-u>call <SID>JumpWithWrap('h', 'l')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-w>j :<C-u>call <SID>JumpWithWrap('j', 'k')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-w>k :<C-u>call <SID>JumpWithWrap('k', 'j')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-w>l :<C-u>call <SID>JumpWithWrap('l', 'h')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-w><Left> :<C-u>call <SID>JumpWithWrap('h', 'l')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-w><Down> :<C-u>call <SID>JumpWithWrap('j', 'k')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-w><Up> :<C-u>call <SID>JumpWithWrap('k', 'j')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-w><Right> :<C-u>call <SID>JumpWithWrap('l', 'h')<CR>
```

Comment: Crap, this skips over netrw for some reason

Answer (score 4):

One can use

```
<C-w>w
```

and

```
<C-w>W
```

to cycle through all the windows to the right/down and left/up, respectively. Both commands wrap around, so `<C-w>w` will end up top left at some point and `<C-w>W` is going to end up bottom right at some point.

See `:h window-move-cursor`.

Or simply use `<C-w>b` which goes directly to your target window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Lua version of the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13855458) if you use Neovim:

```lua
local function try_jump_window(direction, count)
  local prev_win_nr = vim.fn.winnr()
  vim.cmd(count .. "wincmd " .. direction)
  return vim.fn.winnr() ~= prev_win_nr
end

local function jump_window_with_wrap(direction, opposite)
  return function ()
    if not try_jump_window(direction, vim.v.count1) then
      try_jump_window(opposite, 999)
    end
  end
end
local opts = { silent = true, noremap = true }
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-w><C-h>", jump_window_with_wrap("h", "l"), opts)
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-w><C-l>", jump_window_with_wrap("l", "h"), opts)
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-w><C-j>", jump_window_with_wrap("j", "k"), opts)
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-w><C-k>", jump_window_with_wrap("k", "j"), opts)
```